# Book about man jumping between dimensions and selling things from his dimension that are more valuable in the other

Tags: story-identification, magic

I remember reading this a few years ago. A man who realizes he can teleport to another dimension where women outnumber men, silver is more valuable than gold, magnets and steel increase latent magical powers.

He jumps back and forth between this world and the other, opens a shop to sell his world's items. He falls in love with the female sheriff of the town who has heightened strength and speed and ends up running against a bandit lord who kills the sheriff.

Comment: My first thought was *The Merchant Princes*, but that's a female protagonist. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merchant_Princes)